# Can I have text layout page for my enterprise wiki site collection home page, instead of the default page layout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, page-layout, enterprise-wiki, layouts

I know that inside my enterprise wiki site collection I have a wiki page layout instead of text layout. My question is, can I get a text layout page from my enterprise wiki home page?

Currently inside my enterprise wiki site collection, the home page is a wiki page, while I want it to have a home page similar to the team site home page. Where I can add a web part to show my document library  and calendar events instead of viewing  normal wiki page?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to default.aspx. If it shows up, you can then set it as the default home page.

Edit: Since that doesn't work, since that doesn't work.

1. Go to Site Settings and go to the Page Layouts and Site Templates Settings link. In the Page layouts section, add (Welcome Page) Blank Web Part Page and any other page layouts you may want.
2. Go to your Pages library and go into the Library Settings. Click the link for Add from existing Content types.
3. Add Article Page, Welcome Page to your library.
4. Create a new page from one of these content types and select one of the page layouts from step 1.
5. Go to the newly created page and in the ribbon, click Make Homepage.

Comment: i try accessing the defautl page as follow http://..../sites/testwiki/Pages/default.aspx, but i got "Page not found error"...

Comment: should be http://..../sites/testwiki/default.aspx

Comment: same i got page not found

Comment: Then this must only work if you start from a team site template or something similar and add a wiki library to it instead of trying to convert an enterprise wiki to more of a team site.

Comment: but as you know having enterprise wiki site collection offers more features and capabilities compared to just adding a wiki library inside a team site.. so that why i do not want to start from a team site

Comment: I don't know, the only real difference I see is in an Ent Wiki site vs a wiki library is the ratings are on the page whereas in a wiki library they are in the list view. Maybe it's just me, but I always find the specialized templates are too limiting because owners always want something different. I use team sites or project sites exclusively and turn on features or apps to get the desired effect than pigeon holing into a set template.

Comment: but one of the main differences i found , is that inside the enterprise wiki you can when adding/editing wiki pages to add the metadat info such as the built-in wiki category, while in the wiki library you can not do this and you have to edit the wiki page properties, also i think metadata navigation is not available inside the wiki library (although i did not test this). so enterprise wiki site offers more capabilities over wiki page library. also it is very flexible to customize the enterprisewiki page layout, unlike customizing the text layout offered by the wiki library ...

Comment: Updated answer with how to do it.